# Substring em Bash

Tags: bash

Estou a tentar obter uma parte de uma linha em um ficheiros de texto em bash
mas em vez do texto 'campo1' queria usar uma variável. Mas não está a funcionar. Sugestões

FUNCIONA:

```
NomeVar=$(cut -d ":" -f 1 <<< "$(awk /campo1/ { print substr($0,48,10) } /home/ficheiro.txt)")
```

NAO FUNCIONA:

```
fld1=campo1

NomeVar=$(cut -d ":" -f 1 <<< "$(awk /$fld1/ { print substr($0,48,10) } /home/ficheiro.txt)")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faça desta forma:

```
cut -d ":" -f 1 <<< "$(awk "/$fld1/ { print substr(\$0,48,10) }" /home/ficheiro.txt)"
```

Outra possibilidade é usar pipe, assim:

```
awk "/$fld1/ { print substr(\$0,48,10) }" /home/ficheiro.txt | cut -d ":" -f 1
```

Mais sobre AWK neste post: http://rberaldo.com.br/tutorial-awk/

Comment: Funciona, Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -nlE "/$fld1/ and say m/.{48}([^:]*)/"
```